# Strange behavior using append() when combining items in sub-list

Tags: python, list, append

I need some light to clarify what is going on in this toy example:

```
A = []
X = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
B = -1
for i in range(2):
    S = X[i]
    A.append(S)
    for j in range(3):
        T = S[j]
        S[j] = B
        A.append(S)
        S[j] = T

print('\nFinal shape of A after completion {}'.format(A))
```

I expected to obtain the resulting A as:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [-1, 2, 3],
 [1, -1, 3],
 [1, 2, -1],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [-1, 5, 6],
 [4, -1, 6],
 [4, 5, -1]]
```

... but I am obtaining this:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: `A.append(S)` doesn't make a copy of the list. Use `A.append(S.copy())`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.copy()`

```
A = []
X = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
B = -1
for i in range(2):
    S = X[i].copy()
    A.append(S.copy())
    for j in range(3):
        T = S[j]
        S[j] = B
        A.append(S.copy())
        S[j] = T

print('\nFinal shape of A after completion {}'.format(A))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently, please correct me if I am wrong, when I use ``` S = X[i]``` it only attributed a pointer to S which points to the original string in X?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that